# jQuery toggles active state

Tags: css, jquery-ui-accordion, jquery

I'm implementing this toggles on my page http://www.creativusmouse.com/Hyperion/html/toggles.html and wanted to have the toggle button to remain orange when it's active. Please find bellow the CSS and jQuery code used.
I believe this is something easy to achieve. Hope someone could help me.
Thank you ;)

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){

    $('.toggle-view li').click(function () {

        var text = $(this).children('div.toggle-content');

        if (text.is(':hidden')) {
            text.slideDown('200');
            $(this).children('span').html('<i class="icon-minus"></i>');    
        } else {
            text.slideUp('200');
            $(this).children('span').html('<i class="icon-plus"></i>');    
        }

    });

});
```

/* ======================== CSS ======================== */

```
    .toggle-view {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.toggle-view li {
    margin:0px 0px 25px;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.toggle-view h2 {
    font-size:12px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin:0;
    padding:4px 0 4px 40px;
}
.toggle-view span {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #80acb9;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 2px 4px 2px 2px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.toggle-view li:hover h2 {
}
.toggle-view li:hover span {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0;
    background:#F63;
    color:#fff;
}
.toggle-view .toggle-content {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    display:none;
    padding:10px 35px;
}
.toggle-view ul.square, .toggle-view ul.circle, .toggle-view ul.disc {
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add another class to the span element.

in CSS add the class selector to the for the span, that is the same as the hover one:

```
.activetoggle, .toggle-view li:hover span {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0;
    background:#F63;
    color:#fff;
}
```

and in javascript add:

```
$(this).children('span').toggleClass('activetoggle');
```

I think this might work.

here is a little simplified [illustration on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dCxub/)

---

**Update:** I updated the jsfiddle with your markup and code, and I toggle the class now on the `li` element

```
$('.toggle-view li').click(function () {
        var text = $(this).children('div.toggle-content');
        if (text.is(':hidden')) {
            text.slideDown('200');
            $(this).children('span').html('<i class="icon-minus"></i>');    
        } else {
            text.slideUp('200');
            $(this).children('span').html('<i class="icon-plus"></i>');    
        }    
        $(this).toggleClass('activetoggle');
});
```

to simplify everything a little =) The CSS selector is now `.activetoggle span`.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dCxub/1/)

Comment: Thank you. I've tried it but it didn't work. Where do I exactly place that extra line of jQuery?

Comment: mmm it didn't work.
For the plus and minus icons I'm using an icon font. This is the html I'm using:
 
<ul class="toggle-view">      
<li>
<h2>Togle 2</h2><span><i class="icon-plus"></i></span>
<div class="toggle-content">
Toggle content 2 here.
</div>
</li>
</ul>

Comment: Oh ok I'm going to test that now. Thanks

Comment: yes ... I dont have the font, so I just put +/- in ... but now I updated it with everything elese from your page ... and it works for me ... did you try the updated jsfiddle?

Comment: It worked but now I got an issue with the icon font. The jQuery has html('+'); html('-'); and it gets overlapped

Comment: just change the part back in jQuery to `<i class="icon-plus"></i>` and `<i class="icon-minus"></i>` and it will work ... I changed it in html and in jQuery ... so that it worked for me ... they just need to be the same =) I updated the answer with the exact code you should use now.

Comment: No problem, glad to help =D